# How to return an arraylist as response to the restful cxf webservice call

Tags: java, web-services, rest, arraylist, cxf

I'm trying to retrieve the list of documents from MongoDB using restful cxf webservice call. But I'm facing

> No message body writer has been found for response in Class ArrayList.

I had followed [this tutorial](http://www.lessonslab.com/building-restful-webservices-using-apache-cxf/150/). Here they are returning employee object as a response in the `CxfRestServiceImpl` class. So they had used `@XMLElement(name = 'employee')`.

But now I'm trying to return list of documents from MongoDB as a response in the `CxfRestServiceImpl` class. What changes I need to do in order to overcome this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correct, You've got this exception in your code. Than, it is better for you to wrap your List answer in some other class.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="DocumentList")
public class DocumentList {
    @XmlElement
    public List<Document> documentList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Solorad

Answer (score 2):

You can "wrap" into Array like this

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(yourList.toArray(new YourObject[yourList.size()])).build();
```

where yourList is a `List<yourObject>` or `ArrayList<yourObject>`

Answer (score 0):

You can return a list of objects in your service. JAXB will do the conversion from ArrayList

```
@GET
@Path("/employees")
public List<Employee> getEmployees()
```

Ensure that the object has the JAXB XmlRootElement annotation.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Employee")
public class Employee{
}
```